# How to make semi circle bigger?

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts

I am making a simple semi chart with following code.

```css
body { background-color:#555888; }
.sc-gauge  { width:200px; height:200px; margin:200px auto; }
.sc-background { position:relative; height:100px; margin-bottom:10px; background-color:#fff; border-radius:150px 150px 0 0; overflow:hidden; text-align:center; }
.sc-mask { position:absolute; top:20px; right:20px; left:20px; height:80px; background-color:#555888; border-radius:150px 150px 0 0 }
.sc-percentage { position:absolute; top:100px; left:-200%; width:400%; height:400%; margin-left:100px; background-color:#00aeef; }
.sc-percentage { transform:rotate(25deg); transform-origin:top center; }
.sc-min { float:left; }
.sc-max { float:right; }
.sc-value { position:absolute; top:50%; left:0; width:100%;  font-size:48px; font-weight:700 }
```

```html
<div class="sc-gauge">
    <div class="sc-background">
      <div class="sc-percentage"></div>
      <div class="sc-mask"></div>
      <span class="sc-value">Still 0.2 available of 2 GB</span>
    </div>
    <span class="sc-min">0</span>
    <span class="sc-max">2</span>
</div>
```

How to increase this semi circle to a bigger size?

Things I have tried:

```
.sc-gauge  { width: 400px; height:200px; margin:10px auto; }
```

But this doesn't work..

I need to implement like this,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've created an [codepen](https://codepen.io/erikleusink22/pen/RwVrmZJ).

To shrink the semi circle you need to increase the height of .sc-mask to for example 100 and decrease the values of top, left and right to for example 15 instead of 20.

```css
body {
  background-color: #555888;
}
.sc-gauge {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 200px auto;
}
.sc-gauge2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 200px auto;
}
.sc-background {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 150px 150px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.sc-background2 {
  position: relative;
  height: 175px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 150px 150px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
.sc-mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #555888;
  border-radius: 150px 150px 0 0;
}

.sc-mask2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  height: 175px;
  width: calc(100%-30px);
  background-color: #555888;
  border-radius: 350px 350px 0 0;
}
.sc-percentage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: -200%;
  width: 400%;
  height: 400%;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-color: #00aeef;
}

.sc-percentage2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: -200%;
  width: 400%;
  height: 400%;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-color: #00aeef;
}


.sc-percentage {
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  transform-origin: top center;
}

.sc-percentage2 {
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  transform-origin: top center;
}
.sc-min,.sc-min2 {
  float: left;
}
.sc-max,.sc-max2 {
  float: right;
}
.sc-value,.sc-value2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="sc-gauge">
    <div class="sc-background">
      <div class="sc-percentage"></div>
      <div class="sc-mask"></div>
      <span class="sc-value">Still 0.2 available of 2 GB</span>
    </div>
    <span class="sc-min">0</span>
    <span class="sc-max">2</span>
</div>

<div class="sc-gauge2">
    <div class="sc-background2">
      <div class="sc-percentage2"></div>
      <div class="sc-mask2"></div>
      <span class="sc-value2">Still 0.2 available of 2 GB</span>
    </div>
    <span class="sc-min2">0</span>
    <span class="sc-max2">2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. But I am in the need of solution to increase the size of the entire circle.. Please refer the attached image in the question..

Answer (score 0):

Just tried to do something with your code, maybe this might help you. I just doubled some of your parameters. Such as .sc-background, .sc-gauge, .sc-mask and .sc-value. See code bellow.

```css
body { background-color:#555888; }
.sc-gauge  { width:400px; height:400px; margin:400px auto; }
.sc-background { position:relative; height:200px; margin-bottom:10px; background-color:#fff; border-radius:300px 300px 0 0; overflow:hidden; text-align:center; }
.sc-mask { position:absolute; top:40px; right:40px; left:40px; height:160px; background-color:#555888; border-radius:300px 300px 0 0 }
.sc-percentage { position:absolute; top:100px; left:-200%; width:400%; height:400%; margin-left:100px; background-color:#00aeef; }
.sc-percentage { transform:rotate(25deg); transform-origin:top center; }
.sc-min { float:left; }
.sc-max { float:right; }
.sc-value { position:absolute; bottom:5%; left:0; width:100%;  font-size:28px; font-weight:700 }
```

```html
<div class="sc-gauge">
    <div class="sc-background">
      <div class="sc-percentage"></div>
      <div class="sc-mask"></div>
      <span class="sc-value">Still </br>0.2 </br>available of 2 GB</span>
    </div>
    <span class="sc-min">0</span>
    <span class="sc-max">2</span>
</div>
```